# Ant Design Transfer Component. Separate functions for the transfer buttons

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

https://ant.design/components/transfer/

Hey all! I was just wondering is it possible to implement two separate functions on the transfer buttons. For example, I want to run add function when the user clicks transfer to the right and I want to add remove function when the user clicks transfer button to the left.

From the documentation all I could see was both the buttons just trigger onChange function and I dont want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API of `Transfer` component uses only one function to change the data, but you can call different functions inside `onChange` depending on the direction:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Transfer } from "antd";

const mockData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  mockData.push({
    key: i.toString(),
    title: `content${i + 1}`,
    description: `description of content${i + 1}`
  });
}

const initialTargetKeys = mockData
  .filter((item) => +item.key > 10)
  .map((item) => item.key);

const App = () => {
  const [targetKeys, setTargetKeys] = useState(initialTargetKeys);
  const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = useState([]);

  const handleAdd = (nextTargetKeys, moveKeys) => {
    console.log("add");
    setTargetKeys(nextTargetKeys);
  };
  const handleDelete = (nextTargetKeys, moveKeys) => {
    console.log("delete");
    setTargetKeys(nextTargetKeys);
  };

  const onChange = (nextTargetKeys, direction, moveKeys) => {
    if (direction === "left") {
      handleDelete(nextTargetKeys, moveKeys);
    } else {
      handleAdd(nextTargetKeys, moveKeys);
    }
  };

  const onSelectChange = (sourceSelectedKeys, targetSelectedKeys) => {
    setSelectedKeys([...sourceSelectedKeys, ...targetSelectedKeys]);
  };

  return (
    <Transfer
      dataSource={mockData}
      titles={["Source", "Target"]}
      targetKeys={targetKeys}
      selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
      onChange={onChange}
      onSelectChange={onSelectChange}
      render={(item) => item.title}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```